# Google Chrome Viewport Responsive UI option

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, responsive-design

How to enable the View Port option in Chrome without having any plugin.
I want to see the pixel size and see the responsive UI.

The below article doesn't show where the option is available in Chrome settings.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports?hl=en#media-queries

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using developer tools. In that you should click on the "toggle device mode icon" (second from the top).In that you have options to change the viewport according to your needs. Only the interface has changed rest is same.
You can also use the extension "viewport Dimensions" for this.